tfl.assign_variable error when converting saved model to tflite
I am receiving this error when I tried to convert to tflite:
Error: 'tfl.assign_variable' op operand #1 must be tensor of 32-bit float or 64-bit float or 1-bit signless integer or 8-bit unsigned integer or 8-bit signless integer or QI8 type or QUI8 type or 32-bit signless integer or 64-bit signless integer or QI16 type or complex type with 32-bit float elements or complex type with 64-bit float elements values, but got 'tensor<2xui32>'
error: 'tfl.assign_variable' op operand #1 must be tensor of 32-bit float or 64-bit float or 1-bit signless integer or 8-bit unsigned integer or 8-bit signless integer or QI8 type or QUI8 type or 32-bit signless integer or 64-bit signless integer or QI16 type or complex type with 32-bit float elements or complex type with 64-bit float elements values, but got 'tensor<2xui32>'
loc(callsite(callsite(fused["ReadVariableOp:", "sequential_1/random_flip_1/ReadVariableOp@__inference___call___7760"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___7851"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): error: 'tfl.read_variable' op result #0 must be tensor of 32-bit float or 64-bit float or 1-bit signless integer or 8-bit unsigned integer or 8-bit signless integer or QI8 type or QUI8 type or 32-bit signless integer or 64-bit signless integer or QI16 type or complex type with 32-bit float elements or complex type with 64-bit float elements values, but got 'tensor<2xui32>'
loc(callsite(callsite(fused["AssignVariableOp:", "sequential_1/random_flip_1/AssignVariableOp@__inference___call___7760"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___7851"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): error: 'tfl.assign_variable' op operand #1 must be tensor of 32-bit float or 64-bit float or 1-bit signless integer or 8-bit unsigned integer or 8-bit signless integer or QI8 type or QUI8 type or 32-bit signless integer or 64-bit signless integer or QI16 type or complex type with 32-bit float elements or complex type with 64-bit float elements values, but got 'tensor<2xui32>'
loc(callsite(callsite(fused["ReadVariableOp:", "sequential_1/random_flip_1/ReadVariableOp_2@__inference___call___7760"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___7851"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): error: 'tfl.read_variable' op result #0 must be tensor of 32-bit float or 64-bit float or 1-bit signless integer or 8-bit unsigned integer or 8-bit signless integer or QI8 type or QUI8 type or 32-bit signless integer or 64-bit signless integer or QI16 type or complex type with 32-bit float elements or complex type with 64-bit float elements values, but got 'tensor<2xui32>'
loc(callsite(callsite(fused["AssignVariableOp:", "sequential_1/random_flip_1/AssignVariableOp_1@__inference___call___7760"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___7851"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): error: 'tfl.assign_variable' op operand #1 must be tensor of 32-bit float or 64-bit float or 1-bit signless integer or 8-bit unsigned integer or 8-bit signless integer or QI8 type or QUI8 type or 32-bit signless integer or 64-bit signless integer or QI16 type or complex type with 32-bit float elements or complex type with 64-bit float elements values, but got 'tensor<2xui32>'
loc(callsite(callsite(fused["ReadVariableOp:", "sequential_1/random_rotation_1/ReadVariableOp@__inference___call___7760"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___7851"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): error: 'tfl.read_variable' op result #0 must be tensor of 32-bit float or 64-bit float or 1-bit signless integer or 8-bit unsigned integer or 8-bit signless integer or QI8 type or QUI8 type or 32-bit signless integer or 64-bit signless integer or QI16 type or complex type with 32-bit float elements or complex type with 64-bit float elements values, but got 'tensor<2xui32>'
loc(callsite(callsite(fused["AssignVariableOp:", "sequential_1/random_rotation_1/AssignVariableOp@__inference___call___7760"] at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall@__inference_signature_wrapper___call___7851"]) at fused["StatefulPartitionedCall:", "StatefulPartitionedCall_1"])): error: 'tfl.assign_variable' op operand #1 must be tensor of 32-bit float or 64-bit float or 1-bit signless integer or 8-bit unsigned integer or 8-bit signless integer or QI8 type or QUI8 type or 32-bit signless integer or 64-bit signless integer or QI16 type or complex type with 32-bit float elements or complex type with 64-bit float elements values, but got 'tensor<2xui32>'

Any suggestions would be great
Here is the model's code:
num_classes = 5

model=keras.Sequential([
  keras.layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
  keras.layers.RandomRotation(0.2),
  keras.layers.Rescaling(1./255),
  keras.layers.Conv2D(16, 3, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  keras.layers.Flatten(),
  keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(num_classes)
])


model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

file_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%S')
filepath = f'./model'
print(f'Best model will be saved to: {Path.cwd() / filepath}')

# Train the model
NUM_EPOCHS = 1
MIN_VAL_LOSS = np.inf
loss_history = [[],[]]
acc_history = [[],[]]
total_train_time = 0.0
# Training loop
# NOTE: This works better than callbacks
for i in range(0, NUM_EPOCHS):
    print(f'EPOCH: {i+1}/{NUM_EPOCHS}')
    start_epoch = time.time()
    history = model.fit(train_images,
                    epochs=1, batch_size=batch_size,
                    validation_data=val_images)
    end_epoch = time.time()
    delta_epoch = end_epoch - start_epoch
    total_train_time += delta_epoch
    print(f'LOG --> This epoch took {delta_epoch}...')
    if history.history['val_loss'][0] < MIN_VAL_LOSS:
        print(f'LOG --> val_loss improved from {MIN_VAL_LOSS} to {history.history["val_loss"][0]}...')
        print(f'LOG --> saving model as {filepath}')
        MIN_VAL_LOSS = history.history['val_loss'][0]
        model.export(filepath)
    else:
        print(f'LOG --> val_loss did not improve...')
    # Keep track of the training history
    loss_history[0].append(history.history['loss'][0])
    loss_history[1].append(history.history['val_loss'][0])
    acc_history[0].append(history.history['accuracy'][0])
    acc_history[1].append(history.history['val_accuracy'][0])
print(f'LOG--> Total training time: {total_train_time}')




you have a training loop implemented to train your model for a specified number of epochs (NUM_EPOCHS). However, there are a few issues and improvements that can be made to ensure your training loop runs correctly and effectively,In your current implementation, model.fit() is missing the validation_data argument. You need to pass both train_images and val_images as tuples (train_images, train_labels) and (val_images, val_labels), respectively. This ensures that the model is evaluated on the validation data after each epoch

You're attempting to save the model if val_loss improves. Ensure that model.export(filepath) is a correct function or method to save your model. Normally, you would use model.save(filepath) to save the entire model or model.save_weights(filepath) to save just the weights.
